# Passing a string to a function in C++

Tags: string, c++-cli

I want to pass a string like "Celcius" into a function that I have but I keep getting errors tossed back at me from the Function.

```
System::Console::WriteLine' : none of the 19 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

I figure I just have something simple wrong.
Can someone point out my mistake please?  Using MS Visual C++ 2010

I've posted the offending code.  The other functions (not posted) work fine.

```
void PrintResult( double result, std::string sType );    // Print result and string
                                                         // to the console
//=============================================================================================
//          start of main
//=============================================================================================
void main( void )
{
ConsoleKeyInfo CFM;
// Program Title and Description

ProgramDescription();

// Menu Selection and calls to data retrieval/calculation/result Print
CFM=ChooseFromMenu();
switch(CFM.KeyChar)    //     ************************************************************
    {                                                                                  //*
        case '1' : PrintResult(F2C(GetTemperature()),"Celsius");                       //*
                 break;                                                                //*
                                                                                       //*
        case '2' : PrintResult(C2F(GetTemperature()),"Fahrenheit");                    //*
                 break;                                                                //*
                                                                                       //*
        default : Console::Write("\n\nSwitch : Case !!!FAILURE!!!");                   //*
    }                       //************************************************************

system("pause");

return;
}
//Function
void PrintResult( double result, std::string sType )
{
Console::WriteLine("\n\nThe converted temperature is {0:F2} degrees {1}\n\n",result,sType);

return;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C++.

Comment: Aside from the fact that it is not valid, it is also not native as it looks like .NET.

Comment: You are using C++/CLI not just native C++.  See the answer from BigBoss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Console::WriteLine` is a CLI(C++.NET) function and you can't pass `std::string` to it, you should use `System::String^` for this purpose.

In native C++ you should use:

```
std::cout << "\n\nThe converted temperature is " << result
    << " degrees " << ' ' << sType << "\n\n";
```

Comment: It's a conversion of a C program I did last term that we need to change into C++. So what do I change the function to because if I just change the output line to std::cout I still get errors and if I leave it as Console::WriteLine with the std::string changed to System::String^ in the prototype it gets cranky over the ^.

Comment: you should use `gcnew System::String(...)` in place of `System::String^`, result of `gcnew Object` is a `Object^`